# Yii2 dropdown selected value

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to show selected value in Yii2 dropdown,

$_GET Value:

```
  $id = $_GET["cid"];
```

Drop down code

```
  $form->field($model, 'userid')
    ->dropDownList(
          [User::getUser()],
          //[ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['active' => '1']), 'id', 'name')],
          ['prompt'=>'Select a user','id'=>'user_dropdown'],    
          ['options' =>
                    [                        
                      $id => ['selected' => true]
                    ]
          ]

        )->label('');
```

but this method is not working!

Comment: Arah.. I just forget to write echo, inside the PHP tags.
<?= echo $form->field(....) ?>

Comment: Also I was missing this line of code: $model->userid=$id;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this.

```
$model->userid=$id;
$form->field($model, 'userid')
->dropDownList(...)
->label('');
```

Comment: I was missing this line of code: $model->userid=$id;

Comment: $model->country = 'United States';
<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList($model['countries'])->label(false); ?>  This did not work for me. What is mistake here?

Comment: @NileshKumar, *probably* your `$model->country` wants a country Id, not its name. So: `$model->country = $countryId` (1, 30, some else).

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you affect the options (your `<option>` elements) by using the **value** attribute's actual value as the array key in the dropDownList options array.

So in this case I have an array of states and the value attributes have the state abbreviation, for example `value="FL"`. I'm getting my selected state from the Address table, which stores the abbreviation, so all I have to do is use that as my array key in the **options** array:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'state')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt'=>'Select...', 'options'=>[$address->state=>["Selected"=>true]]]);
```

The documentation spells it out: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail

Answer (score 6):

i hope this will help you

```
$form->field($model, 'userid')
    ->dropDownList(
          [User::getUser()],
          //[ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->where('id' => $id)->all(), 'id', 'name')],
          ['prompt'=>'Select a user','id'=>'user_dropdown'],    
          ['options' =>
                    [                        
                      $id => ['selected' => true]
                    ]
          ]

        )->label('');
```

Comment: Useful for multiple select as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$model->userid = $_GET['cid'];
$form->field($model, 'userid')
->dropDownList( 
      $items,                   //Flat array('id'=>'val')
['prompt'=>'']                  //options
)->label('');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$selectValue = $_GET['tid']
echo $form->field($model, 'tag_id')
            ->dropdownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Tag::find()->where(['visibility'=>'1'])->orderBy('value ASC')->all(), 'tag_id', 'value'),
                ['options' => [$selectValue => ['Selected'=>'selected']]], 
                ['prompt' => '-- Select Tag --'])
            ->label(false);
?>
```

This code will Auto Select the selected value received as input. 
Where $selectValue will be numeric value received from GET method.

Final output : `<option value="14" selected="selected">NONE</option>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you are using ActiveForm then value of your model field will be used as the selected value. With Html helper dropDownList function accepts another parameter selection [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail). Example:

```
$id = $_GET["cid"];
\yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList('userid', $id, [ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['active' => '1']), 'id', 'name'), [......])
```

Comment: I got this error: Call to a member function formName() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

This is my S.O.L.I.D approach.

Controller

```
$model = new User();
$model->userid = $id; #this line does the magick. Make sure the $id has a value, so do the if else here.
return $this->return('view', compact('model'))
```

But, if you prefer the setter method. Do this...

```
# Model
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function setUserId(int $userId): void
    {
        $this->userid = $userId;            
    }
}

# Controller
$model = new User();
$model->setUserId($userId);
```

View (view is as-is)

```
$form->field($model, 'userid')
->dropDownList(...)
->label('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below:

```
$category = \backend\models\ProductCategory::find()->WHERE(['deleted'=>'N'])->all();

$listData = ArrayHelper::map($category,'product_category_id','category_name');

echo $form->field($model, 'product_category_id')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'Select']);
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the options I've added are unrequired.
What is written in the 'value' index is what dropdown item will be selected as default.
Prompt just displays a first option that doesn't have a value associated with it.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'model_attribute_name')
    ->dropDownList($associativeArrayValueToText, 
    [
        'value'=> $valueIWantSelected, 
        'prompt' => 'What I want as a placeholder for first option', 
        'class' => 'classname'
    ]);
```

You'll find the function that assigns this in the following file:

> vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php
>
> public static function renderSelectOptions($selection, $items, &$tagOptions = [])

Also from the function you can see that you can **add an optgroup** to your dropdown, you just need to **supply a multidimensional array** in where I've put $associativeArrayValueToText. This just means that you can split your options by introducing group headings to the dropdown.